# 404 route redirect on Doc Manager

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a Doc Manager library. I'm having problem with the url routes, The public (frontend) part are on httpdocs with all the stuff (css, js folder, index.php...), and the backend are just on a parent folder. All It's linked to a subdomain.

If I access it on: `https://fondodocumental.fundacioncb.es/` it will give 404 error page with redirection on `https://fondodocumental.fundacioncb.es/folder/0`.

But if I access on https://fondodocumental.fundacioncb.es/index.php it redirect's to `https://fondodocumental.fundacioncb.es/index.php/folder/0` and it works. How can I fix it?

My friend have the same system on his domain and work's when he write: http://archivo.maimona.org/, look how it redirect's.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use .htaccess file for the magic

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```